# How can I serve a GZipped file with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, angular, gzip, web-component

I created simple app used angular elements and http node server. To optimize bundle size i just convert the resulting js file to gz format with current command:

```
"postbuild": "cat dist/cs6-user-widget/{runtime,polyfills,polyfills-es5,scripts,main}.js | gzip > webcomponent/user-widget.js.gz"
```

The file is created correctly, but i cannot serve this type of content with my node server:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 4202;

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var filePath = './' + request.url;
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            fs.readFile('./index.html', function(error, content) {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': contentType });
                return response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            });
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': contentType });
            return response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
});
```

Can You help me to correctly implement node part?

Comment: The web-component/element part has nothing to do with your question; Your question is: **_How can I serve a GZipped file with NodeJS_**

Answer (score 0):

First, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968915/13236005)

If you still want to use node, here is a simple example:

```
const express = require("express");
const gzipStatic = require("connect-gzip-static");
const app = express();
app.use(gzipStatic(__dirname));
app.listen(4000);
```